# Lagrange method VS Gram-Schmidt process

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, orthogonality, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

(If you don't like the generality below, feel free to take $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$ and $b$ positive definite.)

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and let $b = \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be a symmetric bilinear form on $V$; denote $q$ the associated quadratic form.
Assume that $b$ is definite, i.e. $q$ has trivial isotropic cone, equivalently $b$ is nondegenerate in restriction to any subspace $W \subseteq V$. This implies that $V = W \oplus W^\perp$, in particular the orthogonal projection onto any subspace is well-defined.

There are two famous algorithms to find an orthogonal basis, starting with any basis:

- The **Lagrange method** (also called **Gauss reduction** in French, strangely): In coordinates, write $q$ as a sum of squares of linear forms by eliminating the mixed terms.
- The **Gram-Schmidt process**: put $e_1 = v_1$, and compute $e_{k+1}$ as the orthogonal projection of $v_{k+1}$ on the subspace spanned by $(e_1, \dots, e_k)$. Note: I do not scale the vectors to make them have unit norm.

I claim that when both methods are applicable ($b$ is definite), they are dual to each other, in the sense that Lagrange yields a change of coordinates and Gram-Schmidt a change of basis that correspond to each other. I think this is easy to see on a simple example.

I am surprised to not find this connection spelled out anywhere, especially in a book/lecture notes that covers both. But maybe I just didn't search well enough. Have you heard this before?

Comment: Is this a good starting point?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#Via_Gaussian_elimination

Comment: @user3257842: I don't know, maybe? Gaussian elimination and "Gaussian reduction" (Lagrange method) are not the same thing afaik, but they do seem to be related. Still, introducing the "augmented matrix" of wikipedia and trying to relate everything seems more complicated than necessary to me.